# IIS Unhandled Execution Error FileLoadException

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, web

I have deployed a website to the Test Environment server and while it was working fine on the Dev Environment here I'm getting a very cryptic error from IIS.

```
Unhandled Execution Error

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileLoadException: 

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: 


[FileLoadException]
   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHttpModule.BeginProcessRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +0
   System.Web.AsyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +12336350
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

Does anybody know what may be causing this or is there a way to obtain a better stack trace to see the underlying issue?

Thanks

Comment: did you check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dbe81ttk.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: I'm not getting any assembly name on the exception. Is it because the failing assembly is the application itself?

Comment: it is weird!! Hope Framework is installed and registered with IIS Properly? are there any other .Net apps working on that server?

Comment: There are not other web apps working on that server and is the same assembly that is running on the dev server. Both of them are running on Windows 2012 with IIS 8.5.

I checked and the framework does seem to be registered on the web server. It does appear under the Default Website node on IIS Manager.

Comment: A wild guess... do you have any dependencies / third-party assemblies used in the web app? Are they properly copied / registered? Did you plan to create a test dummy website and deploy on test server to nail down the issue to a specific dll?

Comment: There is a WCF service, but it is not invoked until the user reaches the page where it is needed.